# Nginx Dynamic Reverse Proxy Issue

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I'd like to use reverse proxy feature of Nginx with dynamic URL.

My calling URL would be:

```
http://test.com:8080/10.20.34.53/index.php
```

The dynamic part of the URL is the **IP address**. Then I'd like to call the following URL using Proxy

```
http://10.20.34.53/index.php
```

How can I configure the my Nginx to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

```
location /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/index.php {
    // ... some stuff
    proxy_pass http://$1/index.php;
}
```

Warning: I've not tested the regexp to match the IP address.

Comment: The regex works; however, Nginx redirects to the provided IP even if I add the proxy_redirect off; . How can I solve this redirect issue? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry but maybe I don't understand your question.
The solution I presented is:

 - for each http://test.com:8080/aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/index.php, take the aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd part
 - redirect to http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/index.php


This is not what you need?

Comment: Nope, it should work in a reverse proxy. It isn't supposed to be redirected to another page... So that, whenever user requests: test.com/aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/index.php, nginx should execute the reverse proxy with using aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/index.php